# Specialization of Erdos Gallai Theorem To Vertex Exclusions

Tags: graph-theory

The Erdos Gallai theorem says that a degree sequence $d=(d_1,\cdots,d_n)$ corresponds to a graph iff it satisfies:

$$\sum_{i=1}^kd_i\leq k(k-1)+\sum_{i=k+1}^n\min(k,d_i).$$

Is there a specialization of this result to allow for additional exclusions on possible connections in the graph? Something like for each vertex $v_i$ there is an exclusion list of vertices which cannot connect to $v_i$? For example, $v_1$ cannot connect to $v_2,v_3$.

Comment: By vertex $v_i$ do you mean the vertex with degree $d_i$, or are you not given the correspondence between vertices (as relevant for the exclusion list) and their degrees?

Comment: @Misha Lavrov: exactly so vertex $v_i$ has degree $d_i$.

Comment: How did Erdös figure that out!!? That guy's mind just _baffles_ me. ¶ Do you mean, though, ∀k∊{1 ... n}? I would _surmise_ that it does occasion that qualifier ... but I am not _certain_; and it would be a lovely finishing-touch if you would say explicitly whether it does.